# Tool Bar of TinyMCE images are not getting loaded in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, tinymce-4

I have combed through all the solutions provided for this everywhere, yet my toolbar images are not getting loaded in firefox. Works fine in IE 8
This is my code :

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
    "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
    "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
    ],
    content_css: "/ipe/resources/styles/vendor/content.min.css",
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l ink image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
    style_formats: [
    {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
    {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
    {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
    {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
    {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
    {title: 'Table styles'},
    {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}

    ]
    });
```

I don't have moxie manager, and i also set security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false. Nothing seems to work. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#docsta",
    height : 650,
    mode : "textareas",
    'plugins': [ 'save','advlist','lists' , 'image' ,'charmap', 'print', 'preview'],
    'toolbar': 'insertfile undo redo |  bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify|    bullist numlist outdent indent | save | print | link image | fontselect | fontsizeselect ',                   
    forced_root_block : "",
});
</script>
```

try this it works on firefox on mine